# Infinite loop in ZF2 dependency injection

Tags: loops, zend-framework2, factory, code-injection

I have a service that's using an injected Builder. This builder requires a generator (so the generator is injected in the builder). This generator uses the service described in the beginning (to fetch a number of results).

I think it's pretty obvious there's an infinite loop between the service > builder > generator > service again.

These 3 elements have a factory (implementing FactoryInterface), that's where the injections are done.

I'm in a bit of a rush and maybe cannot see things straight. That's why a bit of advice would be greatly appreciated.

If things are a bit confused and require clearer explanations, I'm sorry and I'd be glad to oblige.

Comment: Code code code. Please show us the code. In this case also the config I think. In the code, please indicate where you think it goes wrong. You asked this a while ago, so if you've solved it in the meantime, please post a solution or remove the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

I followed a coworker's idea: create "writing" methods in a separate WriterService, and this way, have "reading" and "writing" methods in 2 distinct services. This way, I avoid having a loop.

Not sure this is the ideal way but it definitely works in my case.

Regards